# How to make the fowling data conversion: NSArray to char

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Well I'm currently calling a method that requires one char input method, but I the data for it is loaded from a file than putted into an array and then I want to convert one of the array's elements to an const char (all the array's elements are URL's). What basically I'm trying to do is to make the program to load a specific file and then put the lines separately into the array's elements (I mean: 1 line = 1 new array element), and then I made a for loop like this:

```
NSUInteger nElements = [array count];
int i;
for (i = 0; i<nElements; i++) {
    const char* urlName = [[array objectAtIndex:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // I don't know if this is correct but don't works :)
}
```

Comment: You ordinarily don't need to use `objectAtIndex:` to walk through the array. Fast enumeration is both faster and clearer. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an array of `NSURL` objects you'd have to convert them to strings like this:

```
const char* urlName = [[[array objectAtIndex:i] absoluteString] UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's an array of NSString, you could do this:

```
const char* urlName = [[array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
```